# add field directly to a Document library or via a Content Type

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, content-type, spfield

What is differents between adding a field (Site column) directly to a document library or via adding the field to a content type and then add this content type to the list?

Because fields directly added to a document library are sychronized with the property of the documents which are uploaded to the library. but if the fields have been added via a content type they will not be sychronized with property of uploaded documents.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a field to content type will make it reusable and hence can be used in other lists as well by adding the content type to the lists.

Comment: thanks for your answer, as you know the reason I answered this question is when I add fields via a content type they will not be mappad to property of the document I upload to document library. but when I add fields directly to a list the fields are mappad to properties of the document that is uploaded to the list (in both case fields has same name as property ) I am wandering why?

Comment: The reason being when you add a field directly to a list it gets attached to the default content type of that list and hence appears in the properties when you do the upload document. Same can be achieved with a field added to content type. In this case add the content type to the list and when you try to add new item make sure you are using the new content type while selecting from the list of available content types. You can also delete the content types from the list and keep only the one you need.

Comment: there is only one content type "Document" on the list (document library). and I changed this content type which is default.